# How to create a gRPC network connection in an AWS subnet?

Tags: amazon-ec2, grpc, subnet

I have gRPC client-server architecture on 2 EC2's in an AWS subnet. It is a simple HelloWorld app just to show a connection across EC2's.  I am getting the following error:

Status(StatusCode=Unavailable, Detail="failed to connect to all addresses")

I can connect when I run the server and client on the same machine with local host addresses.

I am using Server Credentials of "Insecure" which maybe a problem with AWS.

```
// The server and client snippets are as follows:
Server server = new Server
{
    Services = { HpcService.BindService(new ServerImpl()) },
    Ports = { new ServerPort("localhost", Port, 
    ServerCredentials.Insecure) }
};

// Client 
channel = new Channel(ipAddress, ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
client = new HpcService.HpcServiceClient(channel);
```

I would expect the connection to go through as the security groups allow all traffic.
Thanks,